# functional analysis with the axiom of determinacy

Tags: functional-analysis, alternative-set-theories

I was wondering if any mathematician has tried to develop functional analysis with the axiom of determinacy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Hahn-Banach theorem requires the Boolean ultra-filter theorem which is stronger than the axiom of determinacy. Do people who do functional analysis want to give up the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: @Jay Hahn-Banach theorem is not stronger than the axiom of determinacy. It contradicts with the AD.